# Cloudant couchdb query custom sort

Tags: sorting, couchdb, cloudant

I want to sort the results of couchdb query a.k.a mango queries based on custom sort. I need custom sort because if `Status` can be one of the following:

1. Active = 1
2. Sold = 2
3. Contingent = 4
4. Pending = 3

I want to sort the results on `Status` but not in an alphabetical order, rather my own weightage I assign to each value which can be seen in the above list. Here's the selector for `Status` query I'm using:

```
{type:"Property", Status:{"$or":[{$eq: "Pending"}, {$eq:"Active"}, {$eq: "Sold"}]}}
```

If I use the `sort` array in my json with Status I think it'll sort alphabetically which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually looking for results based on "Status". You can create a view similar to this:

```js
function(doc) { if (doc.type == "Property") { emit(doc.Status, doc);}}
```

When you use it, invoke it 4 times in the order you need and you'll get the result you need. This would eliminate the need to sort.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to achieve this with cloudant query mango indexes